# Primefaces AutoCompleteBean loses its list of selected objects

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, autocomplete

I have to make autocomplete with multiple selections, all selected items has to be unique. I want to filter already selected values in completeRole function. But completeRole function gets null selectedRoles list. What I am doing wrong? AutoCompleteBean is created new with empty list each time I want to select item in autocomplete input? How can I solve this problem?

AutoCompleteBean.java

```
package primefaces.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import bpm.beans.entities.Roles;

@ManagedBean(name = "autoCompleteBean")
public class AutoCompleteBean {

    private List<Roles> rolesDB;
    private List<Roles> selectedRoles;

    public AutoCompleteBean() {
        rolesDB = RolesBean.getRolesDB();
    }

    public List<Roles> completeRole(String query) {
        List<Roles> suggestions = new ArrayList<Roles>();  

        List<Roles> rl = getSelectedRoles();
        for(Roles p : rolesDB) {  
            if(p.getTitle().startsWith(query)) 
                if(rl==null){
                    suggestions.add(p);  
                }
                else if (rl.indexOf(p) < 0)
                    suggestions.add(p); 
        }  
        return suggestions;  
    } 
}
```

roles.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:autoComplete value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedRoles}" completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.completeRole}"  
            var="p" itemLabel="#{p.title}" itemValue="#{p}" converter="rolesConverter" multiple="true" 
            id="autoComplete" >  
            <p:column style="width:100%">#{p.title}</p:column>  
        </p:autoComplete> 
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to preserve selection across multiple requests, your bean must be at least `@ViewScoped`.

and you have to process your selection and update your bean instance. add ajax:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{autoCompleteBean.selectedRoles}" completeMethod="#{autoCompleteBean.completeRole}"  
        var="p" itemLabel="#{p.title}" itemValue="#{p}" converter="rolesConverter" multiple="true" 
        id="autoComplete" >  

    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@this" update="@this"/>

    <p:column style="width:100%">#{p.title}</p:column>  
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. In addition I forgot to update RolesConverter.java fixing it made it all working.